# Join as shapes moves my mesh to a new position

Tags: shape-keys

When I make a shapekey by using "join as shapes" operation, if a deformed mesh which I am trying to turn into a shapekey has its location applied, this location also gets recorded to the shapekey and it moves my main mesh to the deformed mesh's position.
It also happens if I try to make a shape key out of an armature animation, location of the mesh in the scene at the moment of pressing "save as shape key" on armature modifier gets recorded to the shape key as well.
How can I prevent this from happening?
[image]
[image]

Comment: From what I see Join as Shape will copy the shape of the mesh of the first selected object, and it will take the location of the mesh relatively to the origin, if this is what you mean, Transfer Shape Key won't, can you use it instead?

Comment: Transfer Shape Key does not work in this case - because deformed mesh's shape is not recorded into a shape key, so, there is nothing to transfer.
I tried it with shape keys I got out of "save as shape key" on an armature modifier, and it still changes position of my mesh all the same. 
Because "save as shape key" on armature modifier also record the location on the shape key it saves, so "Transfer shape key" transfers that data as well.

Comment: Can't you just create a shapekey for the mesh you want to copy and you'll delete it afterwards?